# Python - how to repair string splitting?

Tags: python, string

```
import requests
f1 = open("domain_list.txt", "r")
domain = f1.readline()
domain_split = domain.split('.', 1)
print(domain)
url = ("https://onestoreapi.home.pl/domains/"+domain+"/search")
content = requests.get(url)
x = ('"fqdn":"{0}","name":"{1}","extension":"{2}","status":"Available"'.format(domain,domain_split[0],domain_split[1]))
find = content.text.find(x)
if find>0:
    print("Domain "+domain+" is available")
else:
    print("Domain "+domain+" is unavailable")
```

Hello, I'm having problems with string "x". It's getting splitted to three lines and I must have it in 1.

"domain_list.txt" includes names of websites like nike.waw.pl

How x looks like:

```
"fqdn":"nike.waw.pl
","name":"nike","extension":"waw.pl
","status":"Available"
```

How x should look like:

```
"fqdn":"nike.waw.pl","name":"nike","extension":"waw.pl","status":"Available
```

How to repair it?

Comment: Replace the line breaks with empty strings?

Comment: Should the "repaired" version be missing the ending quote in the original?

Comment: You didn't strip the newline from `domain`: `domain = f1.readline().strip()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `domain` ends with a newline, which is then incoporated into `x`.

```
domain = f1.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

will remove it, so that either `domain` nor `domain_split[1]` will end with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use strip before split:

```
domain_split = domain.strip("\n").split('.', 1)
```